# How to cancel a background worker with sleep?

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker, thread-sleep

I'm having trouble canceling a background worker that has a `Thread.Sleep(100)` in it.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
        int count;
        try
        {
            count = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((int)(((double)(i + 1) / count) * 1000));
                //Computation code
                Thread.Sleep(int.Parse(textBox4.Text));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            request.DownloadData(url);
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
}

private void cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
    progressBar1.Value = 0;
}
```

If I remove the `Thread.Sleep(100)` then the cancel works but otherwise it just keeps going (the progress bar doesn't stop).

EDIT: Added the rest of the code

Comment: Can you post the rest of the loop? Does it check some flag on each iteration? Does reducing the sleep time, say to 1 solve the problem?

Comment: that Sleep(100) is in processing loop?

Comment: Incomplete code. Just the Sleep(100) call could only _delay_ cancelling a little. There must be something else.

Comment: There was a similiar question on stackoverflow. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800767/how-to-kill-background-worker-completely

Comment: Well the only thing I added was put the Sleep(100) within a try-catch.

Comment: Ouch. You can't access textboxes from DoWork and you're main action is inside a catch? And there is no Cancel support in your DoWork.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call CancelAsync it just sets a property called `CancellationPending` to true. Now your backgroundworker can, and should, periodically check if this flag is true, to gracefully finish its operation. So you need to split your background task into pieces where you can check for cancelation.

```
private void DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            if(worker.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }

            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1 However this doesn't explain how it **was** working without the Thread.Sleep.

Comment: @Joey - Yes of course it does.  We don't know what the loop was actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

Use Thread.Interrupt to exit from WaitSleepJoin state when you want to cancel the background thread.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.interrupt.aspx

Comment: I think interrupting a thread is a bad thing to do if there is a more graceful way (i.e. using worker.CacellationPending).

Comment: Thread.Interrupt is just to exit from the sleep state when you want to cancel. After that, you catch ThreadInterruptedException and check for CancellationPending.

Comment: I would prefer making the sleep shorter so you don't have to worry about catching a `ThreadInterruptedException`.