# Change button content in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, button, mouseevent

I have:

```
private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i > 2; i++) 
    {     
        button1.Content = Convert.ToString(i);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);     
    }

    tekst.Text = "Mouse Enter";
}
```

When I enter on `Button` I see only *`Mouse Enter`*, but `Content` on `Button` don't change. Why? What I can do wrong?

Comment: What is `tekst`? and can you be more clear on what your problem is? I cannot understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: The loop condition is wrong. It should be `i < 2`. Having said that, you should not have the loop at all. You should instead use a timer, for example a [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx).

Comment: If you sleep on your UI thread the UI will have difficulty updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop never execute because you have wrong condition, change it to following code:

`for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)`

Also you should use `BackgroundWorker` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) to update your GUI dynamicly.

```
private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += delegate
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => { btn.Content = Convert.ToString(i); }));
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }                
    };
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate { tekst.Text = "Mouse Enter"; };
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but how to stop this worker when i move out from button

Comment: I think that this question will be helpful if you want to stop execution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800767/how-to-kill-background-worker-completely

Answer (score 2):

Hi is your for loop correct? It should be i<2 instead of i>2

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
```