# Terminate backgroundworker in .net 4

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker

statusbar.cs

On load of StatusBar form,i am calling the backgroundWorker1.In `backgroundWorker1.DoWork` i am calling the  `Login(Username, Password);` function which is also in the same `statusbar.cs` file.

```
private void StatusBar_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, args) =>
            {
                Close();
            };
            backgroundWorker1.DoWork +=
                (o, args) =>
                {
                    Login(Username, Password);

                };
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

Login(Username, Password)
{
  if(Authenticated)
  {   
     MessageBox.Show("Success");
     //do some process
  }
  else
  {
     MessageBox.Show("Failed...");
     return;
  }
}
```

My problem is progress bar is loading correctly.It is showing until i close the `Messagebox`.Once the OK button in `messagebox` is clicked the progress bar disappear.I need to hide the progress bar once the `messagebox` loads/shows.I tried putting `backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();` before the `messagebox` not worked for me.

I need to close the progress bar once the message box appear.Is it possible to terminate the `backgroundworker1` forcibly.

Comment: Post your actual code that compiles (that `Login` method is invalid). Also, where are you currently displaying / hiding the progress bar?

Comment: The `CancelAsync` method just flags to the BackgroundWorker that the task needs to be cancelled. The actual work of cancelling must be done by your process inside the DoWork event.

Comment: Also, you should avoid any blocking methods like MessageBox etc. inside the DoWork. Instead `ReportProgress` and handle the `ProgressChanged` event.

Comment: You haven't shown us where you've used a progress bar? Also I don't see any reason to use `BackgroundWorker` for the posted code. Do you really make use of `BackgroundWorker` ?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800767/how-to-kill-background-worker-completely

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `CancelAsync` method of the background worker, just set a variable inside the process that is working in another thread. Such process must check that variable and stop the action when it is set to false. This variable is in the `DoWorkEventArgs` and it is named `Cancel`.

If you can't control the flow of the action that you want to stop, then I recommend to use the classic `Thread` class. The `Thread.Abort` method raise a `ThreadAbortException` and force to the thread. to stop.